# Outlook 2010 Addon - MailItem.ReplyAll with original body

Tags: c#, outlook, add-in

I'm trying to create a small Addin, which should help me to create a Standard-Email for support-cases.

My procedure is looking like this:

```
private static void CreateAnswer(MailItem item, int pbiId, SupportType st)
{
    MailItem answer = item.ReplyAll();
    answer.Subject = String.Concat(String.Format("[{0}] ", pbiId), answer.Subject);
    Recipient rec = answer.Recipients.Add("Test");
    rec.Type = (int)OlMailRecipientType.olCC;
    rec.Resolve();
    answer.BodyFormat = OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML;

    string ressourceFile = String.Format("OutlookExtender2.{0}.html", st.ToString());
    Stream stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(ressourceFile);
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);
    string text = sr.ReadToEnd();
    string[] senderParts = item.SenderName.Split(' ');

    string rawOrigBody = GetRawHtmlBody(item.HTMLBody);
    string htmlBody = ReplaceBodyText(text, senderParts.Last(), pbiId);

    htmlBody = htmlBody.Insert(htmlBody.IndexOf("</body>"), rawOrigBody);
    answer.HTMLBody = htmlBody;
    answer.Importance = MapImportanceToSupportType(st);
    answer.Display(false);
}
```

Nothing to fancy here, but I'd really like to have the standard-answer with the header (From, Sent, To etc.)

As you can see I'm reading out manually the original text and add it, but this isn't working very well. Is there a possibility to make use of the outlook standard function "ReplyAll", which creates the desired original message?

So the original message should look like this (Sent from my private address):

```
Von: "Matthias Müller" [mailto:testekituks@gmx.ch] 
Gesendet: Mittwoch, 26. Februar 2014 14:48
An: Matthias Müller
Betreff: test from gmx

test from gmx
```

Probably in english or german, doesn't matter that much.

Is there a possibility to let Outlook do this stuff?

Matthias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite follow what you are trying to do.  Do you want to initialize a template with set content whenever you Reply All to a message?  So that the body has  + ?

Comment: If you press in Outlook on "Reply" or "Reply all" etc., you get your Signature and after this you get the original message with the header, which displays from, sent date, to etc.

If I Use the MailItem.ReplyAll() I dont get this Header and the original Message. My question is, is it possible to get this functionality, the header, without programming it manually?

Comment: MailItem.ReplyAll should behave the same way.  Something weird is going on here.

Comment: Wooops I'm the weirdo: As you can see, I'm overwriting the HTMLBody, which overwrites the original-message as well: Error between chair and keyboard.